# Is it possible to a icons and a spinner on an action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to have an actionbar that has a couple of icons and a spinner.

For example my activity will be displaying a map and I would like to have a "refesh" icon, a "fit to markers" icon on as well as a spinner that allows the user to center the map based on a selection from a list of marker names (ie the places marked on the map).

The action bar documentation found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST) says this:

```
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST

List navigation mode. Instead of static title text this mode presents a list menu for navigation within the activity. e.g. this might be presented to the user as a dropdown list.

Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD

Standard navigation mode. Consists of either a logo or icon and title text with an optional subtitle. Clicking any of these elements will dispatch onOptionsItemSelected to the host Activity with a MenuItem with item ID android.R.id.home.

Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS

Tab navigation mode. Instead of static title text this mode presents a series of tabs for navigation within the activity.

Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)
```

Which seems to imply that I can either respond to click of icons, a dropdown, or tabs, but not a combination.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you want to use is `setCustomView()` - this lets you set your own layout for the actionbar in an Activity. So in your Activity you would have code similar to this:

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_layout);
```

And then you would have in your `/res/layout` directory an XML layout file with your Icons and Spinner.

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled on this after asking, now I gotta setup the listeners